# Error 3274 external table not in expected format

Tags: c#, excel, ms-access, excel-2007

I am trying to import Excel file into MS Access (vb cocde )

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, _
    acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "Table", strInputFileName, True
```

and getting the error 3274 (above). The Excel file was generated using Visual Studio 2010 (spreadsheetdocument). 
(Excel file extension is .xls, MS Access- 2010)

Is there any way to make the excel compatible using c#?

Comment: what are the types of fields you are trying to import?

Answer (score 1):

try importing the data to a temporary table, you can then check it for errors before transferring the data to its proper table.

In the excel sheet, set row one as field names - these must be unique on the worksheet and identical to the temp table field names.

Set data type in the access fields for the expected type of data

In row two of the spreadsheet enter typical values.  For a text field use "text" for a number field use 123 for a date field use 25/12/2006 or 01/04/2007

Import the data.

Errors in data type will be flagged in a separate table.  Open this and check which row and column is causing the error.  Go back to the spreadsheet and correct it.

Delete all data in temp table, delete the error table, and then re import, continue until you have no further error table generated.

Transfer the data to its proper table

In case certain fields didn't work you may need to save it as FileType MS Excel 97 - Excel2003 & 5.0/95 Workbook and import the file again